# How to present a job where the company was bought out while you worked there?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I'm working on updating my resume and came across this issue.  The company I work at was bought out almost a year ago, while I continued working there during that time.  To further clarify, timeline would be something like:

- 1 year at Company X
- Company X bought out by Company Y
- 1 more year at Company Y

How should I include this experience on my resume?  Should I format it as 2 jobs?  If not, which company name should I label it with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen this simply listed as "2 years at Company Y (formerly Company X)".  If your role or responsibilities significantly changed between these companies then possibly they should be listed separately or explain the situation in your cover lever if it relates to the position you are applying to.

Answer (score 3):

If you performed the same tasks, I would go for simplicity and keep it a single line

- 1/11/2001 - 30/10/2003: Janitor work at Company X (Company Y since 30/10/2012)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the current name of the company so if the future employer wants to look them up or contact them it is easier.  I'd add a footnote to the end of that job description saying something like:

Note: Position originally with company Y, which was purchased by company X on DATE

I say put this at the end, because it doesn't need to pollute the basic information of the employment dates, job title, and company name that should dominate the start of the listing.  Also, this info should naturally and quickly flow into responsibilities/achievements.  Footnotes can go at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use footnotes for something like this! Add the former company name in brackets. Footnotes force the reader to interrupt his reading and search for a footnote (which is very often also horribly misplaced and consumes a lot of ).

Footnotes are there for two purposes:
Indicate sources and give additional information which does not fit into the text, is of no importantce to understand the text but is still considered important enough to be mentioned somewhere.

Brackets are there for:
Information which is important to the reader (and a former company name is such information!) but which does not fit into the intended flow of your text.

So in short: Former company name in brackets behind the current company name.

Note: This answer was supposed to be a comment, but I'm lacking reputation yet... I hope it helps you though.